# Why does my array output a different result when I append values to it?

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops

Given an array such as `animals = ['ant', 'bear', 'cat', 'dog', 'elephant', 'cat', 'fox', 'goat', 'cat'];`, I am tasked to find the out the number of times the word `cat` appears.

I could carry out out the below function and output the result:

```
let catCounter = 0;
let result = [];

animals.filter(animal => {
  if (animal === 'cat') {
    catCounter++;
  } result.push(catCounter);
});

console.log(result);
```

which gives `[ 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3 ]`.

I only require the end result, which is 3 and I know that I could get the desired result by doing this `console.log(catCounter);`.

Please provide a brief explanation as to why this occurs, and if there is a better way of completing my task, it would be much appreciated if it could be provided.

Comment: `console.log(animals.filter(e => e == 'cat').length)`

Comment: console.log(catCounter)?

Comment: var catsNum = animals.reduce((counter, item) => {
  animal === 'cat' && counter++;
  return counter;
}, 0);

Comment: Why the downvote? I'm curious as to why.

Comment: because you push counter value to array on every loop iteration and console in on loop exit. ask your self why you wrote result.push(catCounter); and console.log(result);

Comment: @NenadVracar I knew I was overthinking this! Any chance you could give an explanation as to why logging my counter results in the displayed array?

Comment: You should read how filter works https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter, it loops through all elements and returns a new array so there is no need to do what you did there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use `Array.push()` method, by doing so, you are appending a value to the *result* array each time you use *push()*. This explain why it result in such an array.

**Let's take it iteration by iteration.**

Assume the following *animals* array `['cat', 'dog', 'chicken', 'cat']`

```
On first loop  =>       increment catCounter (1) and push it to array => `[1]`
On second loop => don't increment catCounter (1) and push it to array => `[1, 1]`
On third loop  => don't increment catCounter (1) and push it to array => `[1, 1, 1]`
On fourth loop =>       increment catCounter (2) and push it to array => `[1, 1, 1, 2]`
```

If you want to count how many cat there is you can do:

```
let catCounter = 0;

animals.forEach(animal => {
  if (animal === 'cat') {
    catCounter++;
  }
});

console.log(catCounter);
```

Comment: Thanks for this. Good explanation as well!

Answer (score 1):

Do like this way:

```js
var arrayVal = ['ant', 'bear', 'cat', 'dog', 'elephant', 'cat', 'fox', 'goat', 'cat'];
console.log(arrayVal.filter(function(e){ if(e=='cat'){return e}}).length);
```